# What does "Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" " means?

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi4

I'm programming a software in C++ with Qt5.15.2. I need to deploy it on a Raspberry Pi 4 and installed Qt Creator and Qt5.15.2 on the Raspberry (I know I can also do a cross-compile but I keep it for later).
When I try to run the the software from QtCreator I get the error :

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl.
```

I googled this error and found threads about how to solve it, especially running the software from the terminal with `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1`

What I didn't find however is a clear explanation of why this is happening.
My questions are the following :

- Why do I get an error ?
- What is the xcb plugin ?
- Did I do something wrong while installing Qt ? If so what did I do wrong ?
- Why is it working with a call to `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1;` ?
- If I deploy my software like this and use a script to call `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1; ./mySoftwareExec` is it an okay or an awful solution ?

I'm really confused about this, this is not clear for me.
This is the output I have when running `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1`before (which I don't understand) :

```
    QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "webgl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWebGLIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("webgl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/eva/eva-core/bin/unix/debug/platforms" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
loaded library "Xcursor"
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platformthemes" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platformthemes/libqxdgdesktopportal.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platformthemes/libqxdgdesktopportal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformThemeFactoryInterface.5.1",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xdgdesktopportal",
            "flatpak",
            "snap"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXdgDesktopPortalThemePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xdgdesktopportal", "flatpak", "snap")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/eva/eva-core/bin/unix/debug/platformthemes" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforminputcontexts" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libcomposeplatforminputcontextplugin.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libcomposeplatforminputcontextplugin.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPlatformInputContextFactoryInterface.5.1",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "compose",
            "xim"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QComposePlatformInputContextPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("compose", "xim")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libibusplatforminputcontextplugin.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libibusplatforminputcontextplugin.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPlatformInputContextFactoryInterface.5.1",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "ibus"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QIbusPlatformInputContextPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("ibus")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libqtvirtualkeyboardplugin.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libqtvirtualkeyboardplugin.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPlatformInputContextFactoryInterface.5.1",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "qtvirtualkeyboard"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVirtualKeyboardPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("qtvirtualkeyboard")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/eva/eva-core/bin/unix/debug/platforminputcontexts" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libcomposeplatforminputcontextplugin.so"
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/styles" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/eva/eva-core/bin/unix/debug/styles" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "gif"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/gif"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QGifPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("gif")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "icns"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/x-icns"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QICNSPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("icns")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "ico",
            "cur"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/vnd.microsoft.icon",
            "image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QICOPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("ico", "cur")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "jpg",
            "jpeg"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/jpeg",
            "image/jpeg"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QJpegPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("jpg", "jpeg")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqpdf.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqpdf.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "pdf"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "application/pdf"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QPdfPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("pdf")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "svg",
            "svgz"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/svg+xml",
            "image/svg+xml-compressed"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QSvgPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("svg", "svgz")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "tga"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/x-tga"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QTgaPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("tga")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "tiff",
            "tif"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/tiff",
            "image/tiff"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QTiffPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("tiff", "tif")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wbmp"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/vnd.wap.wbmp"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWbmpPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wbmp")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "webp"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/webp"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWebpPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("webp")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/eva/eva-core/bin/unix/debug/imageformats" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqpdf.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.so"
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/iconengines" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QIconEngineFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "svg",
            "svgz",
            "svg.gz"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QSvgIconPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("svg", "svgz", "svg.gz")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/eva/eva-core/bin/unix/debug/iconengines" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/accessible" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/eva/eva-core/bin/unix/debug/accessible" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/xcbglintegrations" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.Xcb.QXcbGlIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.5",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb_glx"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbGlxIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb_glx")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/eva/eva-core/bin/unix/debug/xcbglintegrations" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so"
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/bearer" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QBearerEngineFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "connman"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QConnmanEnginePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("connman")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/bearer/libqgenericbearer.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/bearer/libqgenericbearer.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QBearerEngineFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "generic"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QGenericEnginePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("generic")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/bearer/libqnmbearer.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/bearer/libqnmbearer.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QBearerEngineFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "networkmanager"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QNetworkManagerEnginePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("networkmanager")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/eva/eva-core/bin/unix/debug/bearer" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/bearer/libqgenericbearer.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/bearer/libqnmbearer.so"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you only have Wayland available for Qt to use.
`xcb` is part of the X Windows System, [see here](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/).

Not a problem! According to the [wiki page for QtWayland](https://wiki.qt.io/QtWayland), you need to:

> Regardless the only thing you need to do as an application developer to run your GUI application as a wayland client is tell the application to use the right platform plugin:
>
> `./application -platform wayland` or: `export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland ./application`

That environment variable should enable you to instruct Qt to use Wayland. The available plugins listed by that error message could also be passed to `QT_QPA_PLATFORM`.

Comment: The xcb logo cat has unnatural big paws. (You may look onto my profile image for comparison...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got it working launching outside of qtcreator with `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1;`. I tried your approach with wayland but it seems that it doesn't find the plugin when launching while it lists it as available. Thanks for the clarity of your answer !

Comment: @ElevenJune Have you compared `/home/pi/eva/eva-core/bin/unix/debug/platforms/` and `/usr/lib/qt5.15.2/plugins/platforms/`? It might be that `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1;` forces Qt to look for plugins within its installation prefix, even if the project is configured not to do so.